# how to detect the same client in socket.io

Tags: express, socket.io

I am trying to make a chat with **express.js & socket.io**. 
Currently, users in my chat can open multiple tabs on the same browser and can chat over all these tabs. This means that the same client can chat with a few people at the same time. I want to prevent this behavior.

**I want to prevent a client from connecting to chat everytime when:**

1) client works on different tabs on the same browser

2) client opened different browsers and works over them

How i can do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the same user from different tabs in the same browser by using cookies to identify a specific browser.  Upon first connection (either socket.io or an express request), you set a unique cookie identifier and then on subsequent connections, you check to see if that unique cookie identifier is already in use.  You will have to define in your particular application what "in use" means.  For socket.io connections, that's a little easier because it would mean that there is currently already an active connection.  For Express requests, that's a little harder because requests are temporal so you have to decide how you tell the difference between different tabs vs. just one tab navigating to a new page (that's app-specific how you might do that).

For detecting multiple browsers, you will have to have user authentication and either assume users don't make multiple accounts or have some sort of system for preventing the same user from making multiple accounts.  You then use an account authentication credential in a cookie just like in the previous example to tell if a session for this user is already being used.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help!!! For the first case you are right - cookies or sessions will be sufficient for detecting a same user who works on the same browser but on multiple tabs. But for the second case i dont want to provide user authentication at the momemt. I saw a chat that can detect a same client who works on multiple browsers and this chat works without user authentication. I want to do the same.

Comment: i think i found a single solution to my problem. If we use a `socket.handshake.address` to get an ip address of the client we can detect this client everytime when he opens connection over sockets from the same machine.

Comment: @Emil - Because of proxies and NAT and users on private networks, there is no guarantee that an IP address uniquely corresponds to a single user.  A website would see all  users from my house (all from their own computers) as the same IP address because of NAT in our home router.  The same can be true for users from corporations.  So, if you use only the IP address, you will mistakenly deny users their first connection just because somebody else on the same private network is using your service.